# How to abbreviate traceback in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, traceback

I documented an XML-API with Jupyter Notebook, so documentation and specification cannot drift apart.

This works great.

As the API also has to handle invalid input, Jupyter Notebook shows - correctly - the traceback.

The traceback is very verbose - I'd like to abbreviate / shorten it - ideally, only the last line should be shown.

## request

```
server.get_licenses("not-existing-id")
```

## current print out in Jupyter Notebook

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Fault                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-366cceb6869e> in <module>
----> 1 server.get_licenses("not-existing-id")

/usr/lib/python3.9/xmlrpc/client.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1114         return _Method(self.__send, "%s.%s" % (self.__name, name))
   1115     def __call__(self, *args):
-> 1116         return self.__send(self.__name, args)
   1117 
   1118 ##

/usr/lib/python3.9/xmlrpc/client.py in __request(self, methodname, params)
   1456                         allow_none=self.__allow_none).encode(self.__encoding, 'xmlcharrefreplace')
   1457 
-> 1458         response = self.__transport.request(
   1459             self.__host,
   1460             self.__handler,

/usr/lib/python3.9/xmlrpc/client.py in request(self, host, handler, request_body, verbose)
   1158         for i in (0, 1):
   1159             try:
-> 1160                 return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
   1161             except http.client.RemoteDisconnected:
   1162                 if i:

/usr/lib/python3.9/xmlrpc/client.py in single_request(self, host, handler, request_body, verbose)
   1174             if resp.status == 200:
   1175                 self.verbose = verbose
-> 1176                 return self.parse_response(resp)
   1177 
   1178         except Fault:

/usr/lib/python3.9/xmlrpc/client.py in parse_response(self, response)
   1346         p.close()
   1347 
-> 1348         return u.close()
   1349 
   1350 ##

/usr/lib/python3.9/xmlrpc/client.py in close(self)
    660             raise ResponseError()
    661         if self._type == "fault":
--> 662             raise Fault(**self._stack[0])
    663         return tuple(self._stack)
    664 

Fault: <Fault 1: 'company id is not valid'>
```

## my wish output

```
Fault: <Fault 1: 'company id is not valid'>
```

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892383/custom-python-traceback-or-debug-output) might help. They suggest to use a try/except pattern and if it gets an error, grab the traceback to see what it is and respond to it accordingly.

Comment: Hi @MarcosViníciusPetri - thanks for your answer - a try/except pattern definitely would do the trick. I wonder why I have not thought about that :-) Could you write an answer so I can upvote it? Anyway, I'll wait a couple of days, maybe there will be another answer. I bet there is a hook/customization for Python's exception handling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, that's built into iPython, so you don't need to install or update anything.

Just put a single cell at the top of your notebook and run `%xmode Minimal` as the only input. You can also see the documentation with `%xmode?` or a lot of other "magic method" documentation with `%quickref`.

Comment: Thank you so much! This solves a real problem for me! Link to the documentation: https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-xmode

Answer (score 0):

The following solution, using [sys.excepthook](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook) works in a REPL...

### code

```py
import sys

def my_exc_handler(type, value, traceback):
    print(repr(value), file=sys.stderr)
    
sys.excepthook = my_exc_handler

1 / 0
```

### bash

```sh
❯ python3.9 main.py 
ZeroDivisionError('division by zero')
```

... but unfortunately not in **Jupyter Notebook** - I still get the full traceback.

When I have a look at Python's documentation...

> When an exception is raised and uncaught

... maybe the "uncaught" is the problem. When I have to guess, I think **Jupyter Notebook** catches all exceptions, and does the formatting and printing itself.